# inner query in coalesce to set null values

Tags: postgresql, coalesce

I am new in postgres and I would like to set null fields to some other values. When I run this query, it works fine:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Field,'xxx) from Table;
```

However, instead of having 'xxx' for all those fields, I want to fill them like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Field,select id from user where user.id = someOtherTable.id) from Table;
```

In this one, I am getting a syntax error near select.

How can I dynamically set these values?

Comment: Parentheses: `SELECT COALESCE(Field, (select id from user where user.id = someOtherTable.id)) from Table;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Abelisto said in the comment, parantheses around the inner query worked

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear, but probably you are looking for something like this:

```
UPDATE mytable m
SET field = COALESCE(field, o.value)
FROM someothertable o
WHERE m.id = o.id;
```